# Invalid State Of Audio Recorder (Bad FilePath?)

Tags: java, android-studio

I have a recorder I'm trying to make to test it out and see how it works. However when I run it I get the error:

```
E/MediaRecorder: start called in an invalid state: 4
```

So I did some googlejitzu and figured out that my file path is wrong. This is my code:

```
final MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setOutputFile("Test");

    System.out.println("Hello");
    try {
        recorder.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    recorder.start();
    CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long l) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            recorder.stop();
        }
    }.start();
```

So I guess I was wondering how to make a file path directory on the phone for the audio to be saved to.

The Error is:

```
    11-11 01:49:48.275 23703-23703/com.example.arege.dayatalisten W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Test: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
11-11 01:49:48.276 23703-23703/com.example.arege.dayatalisten W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:455)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:247)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:128)
        at android.media.MediaRecorder.prepare(MediaRecorder.java:834)
        at com.example.arege.dayatalisten.ListeningToTheWorld.onStartCommand(ListeningToTheWorld.java:47)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3432)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap21(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1633)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6316)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
    Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
11-11 01:49:48.277 23703-23703/com.example.arege.dayatalisten W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:187)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:441)
        ... 13 more
```

I have both required permissions.

Comment: Why are you catching the error from recorder.prepare() and just printing it and going ahead with recorder.start() ? If prepare() throws a exception, then the Media recorder is in a invalid state. Can you see what kind of exception in thrown my prepare? if it does, please post the stacktrace.
Also make sure you have requested and received permission to write to external storage.

Comment: So I did the recorder.start() like that because thats how it is done in the documentation, so I was trying to be like that. I found the stack error - and posted it. Thank you for guiding me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to write to a internal storage to which your app does not have access. It's not a rooted device.

You need to write your file to the External storage.

Use either: `getFilesDir() or getExternalFilesDir()` (on Context or Activity) to get the directory and write the file to that location.

Psuedocode:

```
File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "Test");
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
outputStream.write("contents".getBytes());
outputStream.close();
```

Comment: So I used: File file = new File(this.getFilesDir(), "Test");
        recorder.setOutputFile(file); However this says that I need an API of 26 to use this method. Is there a work around for this for an API like 21?

Comment: on which method are you getting this message?

Comment: recorder.setOutputFile(file); Specifically. It seems like it just wants me to pass a string name into it

Comment: You'll need to either use setOutputFile(String path) or setOutputFile(FileDescriptor), you can use  setOutputFile(file.getAbsolutePath())